# BRE Policy - Where to Store Connection Strings for Db Facts

Tags: biztalk, business-rules, biztalk-2016, btdf

Using BizTalk 2016 FP3 CU5.

I have a BRE Rule that accepts 4 typed xml documents and a single data connection. 
I've setup an orchestration to execute it using the call rules shape.

I'm using the BizTalk Deployment Framework (BTDF) for deployment and this does a good job of deploying the BRE policies to. My problem is, within the exported xml for the policy (named NotificationService.xml) there's a hard-coded reference to a database used in a rule - as follows:

```
 <datarow ref="db_32" server="SDEIDBTI04\CrossRef" dataset="CrossRef" table="Lookups"
```

This references my dev vm but as the solution is promoted through test and into production, the server name needs to change accordingly.

My current solution to this problem is to use the BTDF's ability to pre-process xml files and substitute with value from the EnvironmentSettings excel file, taken from the SSO. So, I've created a "NotificationService.Dynamic.xml" in which I've changed the previous line to:

```
<!-- ifdef ${_xml_preprocess} -->
  <datarow ref="db_32" server="${Common.Components.CrossRefDbServer}\CrossRef" dataset="CrossRef" table="Lookups" instances="16" selectivity="1" isdataconnection="true" instance="0" />
  <!-- endif -->
```

(*there's a good reason I've had to keep the ifdefs!)

In my deployment.btdfproj file, I have added the following to ensure the pre-processed policy is the one that gets deployed:

```
<FilesToXmlPreprocess Include="NotificationService.Dynamic.xml" 
Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Server'">
  <LocationPath>..\</LocationPath>
  <OutputFilename>NotificationService.Dynamic_Processed.xml</OutputFilename>
</FilesToXmlPreprocess>

<FilesToXmlPreprocess Include="NotificationService.Dynamic.xml" Condition="'$(Configuration)' != 'Server'">
  <LocationPath>..\NotificationService\NotificationService.BRE</LocationPath>
  <OutputFilename>NotificationService.Dynamic_Processed.xml</OutputFilename>
</FilesToXmlPreprocess>

<RulePolicies Include="NotificationService.Dynamic_Processed.xml">
  <LocationPath>..\NotificationService\NotificationService.BRE</LocationPath>
</RulePolicies>
```

This is working but I can't help but think I've over complicated the solution. Each time I export a new version of the policy I now have to go through the hassle of of creating a NotificationService.Dynamic.xml file from the exported NotificationService.xml file. How do people solve the same problem when not using the BTDF?

If it turns out that I've followed the best path then hopefully this question will be of assistance to other in future - I could find no answers from google!

Comment: What exactly are you using the DB connection for?   There are very few instances where I would have a DB connection that is not configured through either a Send Port or Receive Location.  By the look of it you are using it for some lookup functoid for some Cross Ref data?  Do you know that there out of the box Xref functoids that use the BizTalk database tables? https://cdijkgraaf.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/biztalk-pattern-translating-reference-data-in-a-map-using-xref/  For environmental settings like that SSO Configurations is always a good option

Comment: Thanks for your response @Dijkgraaf . I have used the 'standard' BizTalk Cross Ref databases before but they're overkill in this instance. The db connection string is required by the BRE policy, because it's reaching out for a cross ref value for a source value from a xml document that I'm asserting into the policy from an orchestration call rules shape. I am currently storing the connection string in SSO, the BTDF grabs it from them when it creates a deployment. Maybe there's no room for improvement here but I think Johann did this differently, I'm hoping there's a more standard BRE way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd make a static method where you create all the logic getting your lookup value.

So in this method you'd get the SSO `CrossRefDbServer` setting using the [SSOSettingsFileReader.dll](http://www.tfabraham.com/BTDFDocs/V5_0/DeploymentFrameworkForBizTalkDocs.html?ReadingConfigurationSettingsatRu.html), then do some c# code to call your lookuptable and return the value.

You can then call this method in your BRE if you set the registry setting [StaticSupport](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/invoking-static-members-of-a-class) to `1`.